# how to compare the value of a key-value pair from an array in mongoose and retrieve it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have data for batch collection which looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "58d21104a2b6940fd99db632",
    "username": "58d18698669fd20ea0b81720",
    "batchname": "dynamic",
    "time": "21:20",
    "activityname": "dance",
    "eventtype": "demo",
    "duration": 50,
    "price": "120$",
    "__v": 0,
    "trainer": [
      {
        "trainername": "ramu",
        "_id": "58d21104a2b6940fd99db633"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "58d226eb5f73f7150ffc3181",
    "username": "58d18698669fd20ea0b81721",
    "batchname": "spck",
    "time": "21:20",
    "activityname": "dance",
    "eventtype": "demo",
    "duration": 50,
    "price": "120$",
    "__v": 0,
    "trainer": []
  },
  {
    "_id": "58d22745079e481533f23bbe",
    "username": "58d18698669fd20ea0b81721",
    "batchname": "spctygytgyk",
    "time": "21:20",
    "activityname": "music",
    "eventtype": "demo",
    "duration": 50,
    "price": "120$",
    "__v": 0,
    "trainer": [
      {
        "trainername": "siva",
        "_id": "58d22745079e481533f23bbf"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

In that I want to retrieve the details of the batch whose activityname matches with parameter send in the url. I have written the code as:

```
batchrouter.route('/activity/:activityName')
.get(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser,function (req, res, next) {
 Batch.find({"activityname":"req.params.activityName"}, function (err, batch) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(batch);
    });
});
```

when executing the route as `localhost:3000/batch/activity/dance` it is returning an empty array as `[]`. How to modify the code so as i want to retrieve the batch details when the activityname is dance. I am new to mongodb and mongoose. Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing the activityname (`"req.params.activityName" with quotes`) as string instead of actual value. Update the code to following

```
Batch.find({"activityname":req.params.activityName}
```